# Poder copiar en drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código donde puedo mover las filas de una tabla.

Pero si quiere copiar el contenido de unas de las columna no puedo.

Debo condicionar con algo extra? o dejar el evento en `<td>`

```js
let shadow

function dragit(event) {
  shadow = event.target;

}

function dragover(e) {
  let children = Array.from(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children);
  if (children.indexOf(e.target.parentNode) > children.indexOf(shadow))
    e.target.parentNode.after(shadow);
  else e.target.parentNode.before(shadow);

}
```

```css
td{
  padding:5px 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
  background:#ddd;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
  background:#bbb;
}
td { user-select: all; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr draggable="true" ondragstart="dragit(event)" ondragover="dragover(event)">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>nabil</td>
    <td>droid</td>
  </tr>
  <tr draggable="true" ondragstart="dragit(event)" ondragover="dragover(event)">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>testing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr draggable="true" ondragstart="dragit(event)" ondragover="dragover(event)">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td>world</td>
  </tr>
  <tr draggable="true" ondragstart="dragit(event)" ondragover="dragover(event)">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>programming</td>
    <td>javascript</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: en css añade `td { user-select: all; }`

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Gracias, lo agregue y no funciona. No logro copiar contenido de un `td`

Comment: Afirmas que no funciona sin embargo yo perfectamente copio y pego el contenido de cualquiera de tus td....javascript, programming, droid, nabil... todo copiado de tu snippet